# How to switch to year/month directory structure format from a single folder

Tags: uploads, redirect

Currently we have close to 800,000 images in the Wordpress /uploads folder. It's a single folder and not structured on years and months.

Our admin says that there might be an issue with backing up 800,000 images and also for the performance, so we should change the structure to year/month. We run on a dedicated server and so far it's okay.

We're trying to figure out the following:

1. How to achieve this move?
2. What's the impact on SEO and Google Images for example?
3. Will plugins be affected or do they use a relative path and pull the correct URL?

Thank you.

Comment: The `2)` is off topic here.

Comment: True, it shouldn't be there